# Converting parts of a string into different colums of a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a json file containing two colums. The second column is a string. This string has a structure looking like this:

```
"x#y#z"
"aa#bbc#cd"
```

So the string consists of multiple substrings, separated by #. The number of substrings is the same for each row.
I would like to split the strings into columns of a dataframe.I could do so with some substring functions, but looking for an easier method, especially as my real data has 20 substrings. This is my current pyspark code:

```
data = """
{"a":1, "b":"x#y#z"}
{"a":2, "b":"aa#bbc#cd"}
"""

dbutils.fs.put(inputpath + "/001.json", data, True)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.format("json").load(inputpath) \
  .select ("a", "b").withColumn("b1", substring_index('b', "#", 1)) 

df.show()

+---+---------+---+
|  a|        b| b1|
+---+---------+---+
|  1|    x#y#z|  x|
|  2|aa#bbc#cd| aa|
+---+---------+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use split for this (see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=split#pyspark.sql.functions.split)). It splits a string around a pattern (pattern is a regular expression). The result is an array. With this you can easily access the elements in the string:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.format("json").load(inputpath) \
  .select ("a", "b").withColumn("c", split("b", "#")) \
  .selectExpr("a", "b", "c", "c[0] as b0", "c[1] as b0", "c[2] as b2")
```

The dataframe will look like this:

```
+---+---------+-------------+---+---+---+
|  a|        b|            c| b0| b0| b2|
+---+---------+-------------+---+---+---+
|  1|    x#y#z|    [x, y, z]|  x|  y|  z|
|  2|aa#bbc#cd|[aa, bbc, cd]| aa|bbc| cd|
+---+---------+-------------+---+---+---+
```

Hope this helps.